# Cannot add up results of a function in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have this function `getSize()` (from npm module: `get-folder-size`) that's calculating the total size of all files in a folder (directory).

```
const getSize = require('get-folder-size')

let folders = ["C:\\test folder", "C:\\test folder 2\\sub folder"]

funciton totalFilesizeOfAllFolders () {
  let totalSizeOfAllFolders = 0
  this.folders.forEach(folder => {
    getSize(folder, (err, size) => {
      if (err) { throw err }
      // ADD UP THE "SIZE" TO THE TOTAL SOMEHOW
      // Just doing the following returns 0: totalSizeOfAllFolders += size
    })
  })
  return totalSizeOfAllFolders 
}
```

### Question

How do I loop through the array `folders` properly and add up the calculated `size`s of all the folders in the array? I'm not sure how to return the `size` out of the function

Comment: That's an asynchronous API, so you won't be able to return a result. You'll have to structure your own API as something with a callback or use Promises.

Comment: @Pointy so I won't be able to use it in a loop, since loops are synchronous?

Comment: Well you certainly can call the function in a loop; that's not the crux of the problem. Loop or no loop, that `getSize()` function is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Promise.all here, first construct an array of Promises, and then await all of them calculating the total size:

```js
//const getSize = require('get-folder-size')

let folders = ["C:\\test folder", "C:\\test folder 2\\sub folder"];


function totalFilesizeOfAllFolders(callback) {
  let folderPromises = folders.map(folder => { // use map to create a new array of promises
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => getSize(folder, (err, size) => {
      if (err) {reject(err)}
      resolve(size);
    }));
  })
  Promise.all(folderPromises) // promise.all waits for all promises in the array to resolve
    .then(sizes => callback(sizes.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))); // reduce the array of sizes to a size
}


totalFilesizeOfAllFolders(s => console.log(s)); // => 127



// getsize stub. remove me once you have access to the npm package
function getSize(name, callback) {let sizes = {"C:\\test folder":112, "C:\\test folder 2\\sub folder":15}; callback(null,sizes[name])}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer, I get it now

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) to help you iterate over the calls asynchronously then pass a callback to your function to return the `totalSizeOfAllFolders`.

```
function totalFilesizeOfAllFolders (done) {
  let totalSizeOfAllFolders = 0;
  async.each(folders, (folder, callback) => {
    getSize(folder, (err, size) => {
      if (err) { throw err }
      totalSizeOfAllFolders++;
      callback();
    });
  }, (err) => {
    done(totalSizeOfAllFolders);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!